# How is it possible to complete the dataset column in MLflow?

Tags: python, mlflow

As mentioned in the title, I want to complete the dataset column but I don't know how.. I'm new to MLflow. I have a small python application in which there is a dog and cat classification.

[Screen with the dataset column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvSpn.png)

I tried some python line but I didn't find..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

- https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html?highlight=log_input#mlflow.log_input
- https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.data.html#mlflow.data.dataset.Dataset

Example:

```
dataset = mlflow.data.from_pandas(X_train,
  source="wine_quality_white.csv",
  name="wine_quality_white"
)
mlflow.log_input(dataset, context="training")
```